# Submit fields in an InfoPath form to multiple lists

Tags: infopath, data-connection, infopath-rules

I would like to create an InfoPath form that submits two fields to one list, and two fields to another list. Could I use a button with rules that bind to multiple data connections and then promote only certain fields in each connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can only be done with code. You'd either need to write it yourself or use a tool called [qRules from Qdabra Software](http://www.qdabra.com/en/products/qRules_overview.aspx). It's like an add-on for InfoPath that provides functionality that is not available out of the box. It's not free, but it costs less than a day's developer time.